# Angular Chosen not loading selection lists dynamically after page loads

Tags: angularjs, angular-chosen

I use **Angular chosen** to add styles to default select tag in HTML. It works fine when i push my data object to select tag on page load.

But i want to load the list dynamically when other selection list is selected. It does not work here. When i remove the chosen directive it works fine. Here is my code . Thanks

HTML

```
<select chosen ng-model="list_sno"  ng-options="sl.List_Name for sl in sourcelists" > </select>
```

JS

```
myService.getSourcelistsforSource(source_sno).then(
function(data){ 
$scope.sourcelists = data;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the code in $timeout like this

```
$timeout(function(){
    $scope.sourcelists =data;   
    },0);
```

Dont forget to add $timeout dependency above.

Comment: it should work...check out the jsfiddle ...http://jsfiddle.net/p37q0n9e/